# Is it possible to store additional info (just one item) in a TCheckListBox?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, lazarus, tcheckbox

I'm using a list of checkboxes on a form where they are actually TCheckListBox components.

I can use this method to show the clicked item:

```
ShowMessage(MyCheckBoxes.GetSelectedText);
```

In addition to the visible text in each row, I'd like to store an ID number.

Is this possible to do this and if so please share a doc or example.

Thanks!

I'm using Lazarus + Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array with items is called "items".  The texts are in items[i] and you can store additional objects in items.objects[i]

Comment: Thanks! How did you find this?

Comment: It's a common pattern, "items" is nearly always of tstrings (an abstract ancestor of TStringlist), which has this functionality.